# is there any way to write more than 255 bytes using i2c?

Tags: c, i2c

When I send 255 data, all data were sent normally.
However, if I send more than 255 bytes of data, it gets corrupted.

It feels like I have only one page, which can hold only 255 bytes of data. So if I send more than 255 bytes of data, data gets mixed up and corrupted.

> its fixed now!but 257~end of array of data seems not saving..

```
123_DATA_SIZE = 32;
123_PACKAGE_SIZE = (123_DATA_SIZE+2) 
123_tbl_1_SIZE = sizeof(123_tbl_1)
123_tbl_1 = array of data i.e.{0x20,0x24,..,0x67) //assume there are 
                                                    1024bytes of data
123_SLAVE_ADDR = 0x24 /////(initial slave address)
unsigned char ProgramCommand(WORD wAddr) 
{
BYTE I2c_ProgramCommand[123_PACKAGE_SIZE]; // command + addr + data size    
unsigned    char Release_ProgramCommand[3] = {00,00,00};    
unsigned    char Low_ByteCommand[3] = {0x0E,0xFF,0xFF}; 
unsigned int count, count1;
Adding =0;
Adding1 = 0;
wAddr =0;
{
    unsigned char I2c_OnlyOnceProgramCommand[3] = {0xE0,0x00,0x13};
    if (i2c_123_iSP_Write(123_SLAVE_ADDR, I2c_OnlyOnceProgramCommand, 3)==0)
        return 0;
}

for(count = 0; count < (123_tbl_1_SIZE/123_DATA_SIZE); count++)// size 
                                                of data divide by 32                                                                      
{   
    I2c_ProgramCommand[0] = 0x90;  
    I2c_ProgramCommand[1] = wAddr;
```

> changed below

```
     if(count%(7+Adding) ==0) 
        {
         SetAddressHighbyteCommand(0);
            Adding +=8; // for additional pages..
            //  Adding1 +=1;
        }
```

> now i changed above part to

```
 if(count%8 ==0) //
        {
         SetAddressHighbyteCommand((BYTE)(wAddr >> 8));
        }
```

> and this worked! sending more than 256 bytes still shown me correct data.

```
    for( count1 = 0; count1<123_DATA_SIZE; count1++)    // count1 runs total 32 times.
    {
        I2c_ProgramCommand[2+count1] = 123_tbl_1[wAddr+count1];
    }
        if( i2c_123_iSP_Write(123_SLAVE_ADDR, I2c_ProgramCommand, 
           123_PACKAGE_SIZE) == 0)      
            return 0;   
        SetAddressHighbyteCommand(0);
    if(123_iSP_Write(123SLAVE_ADDR, Release_ProgramCommand, 3)==0)      
            return 0; 
    wAddr += 32; 
}
return 1;
}
```

now the problem is, 257~512 bytes of data seems not saving properly.
read command is:

```
void ReadCommand(WORD wAddr) 
{
unsigned    char u8ReadBuffer[256];
unsigned int  u16Cmd_LowAddr =  0xD000;

if(wAddr & 0xFF00)
{
    SetAddressHighbyteCommand((BYTE)(wAddr >> 8));
}

u16Cmd_LowAddr |= (wAddr & 0x00FF);
i2c_123_iSP_Read(0x25,u16Cmd_LowAddr,u8ReadBuffer,256);

#if 1
{
    WORD inx;
    printf("ReadData   --------- \n");
    
    for(inx = 0; inx < 256; inx++)
    {
        printf("0x%02x, ", u8ReadBuffer[inx]);
    }
}
#endif
}
```

when i chenge value of  unsigned int  u16Cmd_LowAddr =  0xD000;
into 0xE000, value shows only 0x00
i also tried 0xf00, but that didnt help neither

Comment: Things like `123_PACKAGE_SIZE`, `123_tbl_1_SIZE`, `123_tbl_1`, `123_SLAVE_ADDR`... aren't valid C code. Please show a real [mcve]

Comment: @phuclv thx for comments. i added more information and current status. now every 256bytes, addr will be moved by 8bits. but somehow they dont get saved at eeprom

Comment: We also don't know what functions like `i2c_123_iSP_Write()` do. Please write what kind of MCU/libraries you are using or post the relevant code. Also the part number of the EEPROM.

Comment: i2c_123_iSP_Write() is nothing but sending byte whatever info i wrote. which includes isp command, finish command erase command...etc

Comment: So those functions can all handle values greater than 255?

Comment: According to spec book, yes. it wraps up 255 bytes into  page 1, ~512bytes to page no.2

Comment: your code is still not valid. There's no way a C compiler can accept a variable with name `123_DATA_SIZE`

Answer (score 1):

A typical I2C EEPROM does not allow writing more than one page at a time. So, if your EEPROM has 256-byte pages and you need to write more than 256 bytes, you need to perform multiple writes.

Here is an excerpt from an ST EEPROM datasheet:

> The Page Write mode allows up to 256 byte to be written in a single
> Write cycle, provided that they are all located in the same page in
> the memory: that is, the most significant memory address bits, b16-b8,
> are the same. If more bytes are sent than will fit up to the end of
> the page, a “roll-over” occurs, i.e. the bytes exceeding the page end
> are written on the same page, from location 0.

Comment: I tested with 1024 bytes, which makes 4 pages.  and i thought this makes  new pages ->>>>>                                                                      if(count%8 ==0) //
        {
         SetAddressHighbyteCommand((BYTE)(wAddr >> 8));
        }<----- is it not? +currently, im testing with 0xD000 as the spec book says. but not so sure what address should i use to look 257~512 bytes of data

Comment: @JH_LEE, multi-page EEPROMs have several I²C addresses on the bus.